# Почему Visual Studio подчеркивает строку #include <stdio.h> языка С?

Tags: c

[image: Файл с расширением .с]

Проблемы такие: "Обнаружены ошибки #include. Измените includePath." и "Не удается открыть источник файл stdio.h"

Comment: VS не может найти файл `stdio.h`. Пути к заголовочным файлам должны быть указаны в `includePath`. Проверяйте настройки оболочки.

Comment: если компилируется, то надо выйти из VS, удалить `.vs`, зайти снова. Это для VS2022.